# Retrofit get unknown fields as Map

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I currently struggle with retrieving an JSON object with retrofit. The problem is, that I don't know the names of the fields in advance. Normally I would map these fields as a Map, but how do I name this retrofit object?

That's how my JSON object looks like:

```
{
    "User{email='john.doe@example.com', id='JDoe'}" : {
        "101" : 1,
        "102" : 2,
        "103" : 3,
        "104" : 2
     },
     "User{email='jane.doe@example.com', id='JDoe01'}" : {
         "101" : 3,
         "102" : 1,
         "103" : 1,
         "104" : 3
     }
}
```

The class for the retrofit object:

```
public static class UserSettings{
    public Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> settingsMap;
}
```

Now what I think happens is that retrofit tries to find a object called 'settingsMap'. But this map is the root element and therefore does not have a name, so the settingsMap is a null object.

Any help to solve this problem is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to change json structure... Now it is not possible to do something with this because for the json structure contains two different objects

Comment: No, I am just consuming the API. I also would prefer another json structure.

Comment: I already resolved your problem, if you have any question just ask.

Comment: I updated my post - I mean `UserDeserializer` class. Let's try my solution one more time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement your own deserialiser for `UserSettings` object. As is shown below:

As first create model for user setting data:

```
public class UserSettings {
        public Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> settingsMap;

    public  UserSettings(){
        settingsMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void add(String key, Map<String, Integer> settingMap){
        settingsMap.put(key, settingMap);
    }
}
```

In the next step prepare API client for you object

```
public interface UserSettingApiClient {

    @GET("/yourEndpoint")
    UserSettings getUserSetting();
}
```

And now is the most important step. You have to create your own `JsonDeserializer` as is shown below:

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<UserSettings> {

    @Override
    public UserSettings deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        UserSettings userSettings = new UserSettings();
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) json;
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> element : jsonObject.entrySet()){
            String key = element.getKey();
            JsonObject obj = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject(key);
            Map<String, Integer> settingMaps = new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> setting : obj.entrySet()){
                String settingKey = setting.getKey();
                Integer integer = obj.get(settingKey).getAsInt();
                settingMaps.put(settingKey, integer);
            }
            userSettings.add(key,settingMaps);
        }
        return userSettings;
    }
}
```

When you do this you have to register this deserialiser in your `GsonConverter`.  The example below shows how to call complete request but  you have to use this solution in the place where you create `RestAdapter`

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
       .setEndpoint("http://your.apiaddress.com")
       .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)//this is not necessary 
       .setConverter(
              new GsonConverter(
                   new GsonBuilder()
                             .registerTypeAdapter(UserSettings.class, new UserDeserializer())
                   .create()))
      .build()
      .create(UserSettingApiClient.class)
      .getUserSetting();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your approach! It looks good to me. However it doesn't work so far, because I get NullPointer at obj.get(setting).getAsInt();

Comment: Does json inside {"101" : 3,
         "102" : 1,
         "103" : 1,
         "104" : 3} always contains 101 102 103 and 104 tags or it can contains different

Comment: I updated UserDeserializer now it is generated solution. Try it now and inform me

Comment: Thank you, this works! And yes: The general solution is better. Althoug I already implemented it this way, my problem was that I had a typo in key.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you :) Good luck